# Json serializer problem. Empty values in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

In `OnModelCreating` method of `DBContext` I specified Conversion options:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
    .Property(g => g.Players)
    .HasColumnName("Players")
    .HasColumnType("BLOB")
    .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, options),
        s => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Player>>(s, options)!,
        ValueComparer.CreateDefault(typeof(Dictionary<string, Player>), true));
```

**Player class**

```cs
public class Player {
    public string UserID;
    public string UserName;
    public string UserToken;
    public byte InGameOrder;
    public string Team;
    public List<Cards> Hand;
    public Player(string id, string name, string token, int inGameOrder) {
        UserID = id;
        UserName = name;
        UserToken = token;
        InGameOrder = (byte)inGameOrder;
        Team = new string[] { "red", "black" }[inGameOrder % 2];
        Hand = new(8);
    }
    public Player()
    {
        
    }
}
```

**How I add players:**

```
var gameFound = await db.Games.FindAsync(sessionName);

if (gameFound.Players.Count() == 0)
{
    gameFound.Players.Add(userToken, new Player(userID, userName, userToken, 1));
}
else
{
    var prevPlayerInGameOrder = gameFound.Players.Values.Select(p => p.InGameOrder).Max();
    gameFound.Players.Add(userToken, new Player(userID, userToken, userName, prevPlayerInGameOrder + 1));
}

db.Games.Update(gameFound);
int affected = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But the values of my Players dictionary in DB are empty:

```json
{"667440114":{},"181308099":{},"1326342467":{}}
```

I've had "Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type must bind to an object property or field on deserialization" so I added a parameter-less ctor in `Player` class

I think, I somehow need to specify ctor of `Player` in Serialization parameters

Comment: Check out the duplicate. `System.Text.Json` by default ignores fields. There are multiple workarounds, arguably the easiest would be to turn fields into properties.

Comment: All serializers ignore fields by default. Fields are internal implementation details, even if they're public, Only properties are part of a type's external interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned the fields of `Player` class into properties (added get set)

Now, It works

```json
{"1812734613":{"UserID":null,"UserName":null,"UserToken":null,"InGameOrder":0,"Team":null,"Hand":null},"601428614":{"UserID":"aerge","UserName":"601428614","UserToken":"rasse","InGameOrder":1,"Team":"black","Hand":[]}}
```